# Selecting array value for data clense

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am fairly new to react and lodash. I am trying to get some data rounded to two decimal places.

```
selectedPlayers {
0: {SHOT__Goals: 1.222222}
1: {SHOT__Goals: 0.888888}
}

 const goals = ( selectedPlayers ) => {
 const goal= _.round((selectedPlayers.SHOT__Goals), 2).toFixed(2);
 return goals;
 }
```

`SHOT__Goals` is coming in as undefined, how do I reference it so it knows to look inside of `selectedPlayers`

I want it to return values like 1.22 and 0.88

Comment: This doesn't relate to react. That tag isn't appropriate here, also there are syntax errors in your example could you resolve them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't need lodash for that, you could use the `Array.prototype.map` function:

```js
const selectedPlayers = [{ SHOT__Goals: 1.222222 }, { SHOT__Goals: 0.888888 }];

const goals = selectedPlayers => selectedPlayers.map(player => player.SHOT__Goals.toFixed(2));

console.log(goals(selectedPlayers))
```

However, for what I gather you don't really want `goals` to be a function but the resulting array if I am right then the following would do:

```js
const selectedPlayers = [{ SHOT__Goals: 1.222222 }, { SHOT__Goals: 0.888888 }];

const goals = selectedPlayers.map(player => player.SHOT__Goals.toFixed(2));

console.log(goals)
```

Something to notice:

- I converted `selectedPlayers` to an array, it is easier to manipulate
- I don't quite get why are you using `_.round` when there is also a `toFixed`

Comment: This is how i would suggest doing it. @Tom

Answer (score 1):

in this case...

```
const selectedPlayers = {
  0: { SHOT__Goals: 1.222222 },
  1: { SHOT__Goals: 0.888888 }
}

const goals = selectedPlayers => {
  return _.round(selectedPlayers[0].SHOT__Goals, 2).toFixed(2)
}

console.log(goals(selectedPlayers))
```

Your example had a lot of issues, which i fixed. There are better ways of doing this however....